# OpenCV hardware acceleration in Java

Tags: java, opencv, hardware

I build social project for object detecting with OpenCV+RaspberryPi. I wanna use hardware acceleration in my project. I found manuals for C++, but nothing for Java. Can you get me some information about it?

Comment: OpenCV's java port is in my experience somewhat incomplete, and not entirely intuitive. If possible, I'd highly recommend writing your OpenCV code in Python or C/C++ instead. If anything for the greatly superior docuimentation available for it.

But what exactly are you asking here? Your question is really general and I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: I get RTSP stream from WiFI cam and I want to handle this stream through the GPU in Java